# Manga where the MC has a gate or space ability and builds a bath in his home

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga where the MC has a gate or space ability. He builds in his home a big bath with magic stone that heats up the water that he found from a monster that lives in a cave. He received an uninvited visit from his brother in law and they end up fighting because the in law is a siscon and doesn't want the girl to be with the MC. The MC beats him and they end up taking a bath together. After that, accepting him, his brother-in-law respects him. The girl and the in-law are nobles or royalty.

Comment: Do you remember anything about his wife (fiancee? girlfriend?)? Such as how they met, why/how they're together or if she has any unique powers/skills? Is the MC reincarnated/transmigrated into another world?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Unfortunately for me I don't remember even how the mc looks and how his fiancee or GF looks , for whatever reason I just remember that fight and bath scene